# JFreeChart : Dynamically change the Series list

Tags: java, jfreechart

Please, how can I update the Series of the JfreeChart.
My Jfreechart works like this, 
I have a set of CheckBox, when I select the checkboxes from which I want to retrieve informations I would like to see them on the series zone of my graph.
The Series list are changing but there are not showing. How can do it inside the code ?
thanks

Edit
This is how my code is written

```
 public DrawChart(JPanel panel){
    this.refresh = new RefreshGraph();
    this.displayChart (panel);
}

private void displayChart(JPanel jpanel){
    final DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

    Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            refresh.getRefresh (dataset);
        }
    });
    timer.start ();

    JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);

    ChartPanel panel=new ChartPanel(chart);
    panel.setPreferredSize (new Dimension(700,300));
    jpanel.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());
    jpanel.add (panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    jpanel.repaint ();
    jpanel.setVisible(true);
}

private JFreeChart createChart(final CategoryDataset dataset){
    final JFreeChart result = ChartFactory.createLineChart ("", null, null, dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
    return result;
}
```

and this is how I fill the dataset

```
dataset.addValue (Double.parseDouble (separateValues[0]), _listSeries.get (0), aLine);
dataset.addValue (Double.parseDouble (separateValues[1]), _listSeries.get (1), aLine);
```

What I need is that , when the Timer is running every 1 second, the _listSeries (which represents the list of all the series to be displayed) also change. Only the values in the graph are changing no the Series zone.
How can I do it?
I was thinking to refresh the panel by calling repaint() but no way. it does not work.
Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows your current approach.

Comment: I have already edited @trashgod

Comment: Your example is _mot_ complete. What is a _Series zone_?

Comment: this is solved.
to refresh the chart, i just clear the dataset when I declare it. That is

    dataset.clear ();

and the chart is refreshing at every click.

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/163188).